# Taking the average of a column in a matrix and putting it in an array is giving me this error:[D@55f96302

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods

Every time I run my program, instead of printing out an array containing the averages, it prints out `[D@55f96302`. What's causing this, or what does it mean?

The method in question is supposed to calculate the average of each individual column in a matrix, and put that average into an array, and then print the array.

Column average and print method:

```
public static void columnAverage(double [][] matrix, double[] array) { 
    double sum, average;
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix.length; c++) {
    sum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){ 
            sum = sum + matrix[r][c];
            average=sum/matrix.length;
            array[r]=average;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("averages" + array);
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many students are there?");
    int students=kb.nextInt();
    double [][] grades= new double [students][4];   
    double[] averages= new double [4];
    getScores(grades);
    rowAverage(grades);
    System.out.printf("%10s","Student");
    printMatrix(grades);
    System.out.println();
    columnAverage(grades, averages);
    kb.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's printing out the `toString` (ie, the debug name) of an array of double.  You can't print the contents of an array by simply doing `println` on it.  You need to use [*Array.toString*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double[]%29).

Comment: wait cant I put a `System.out.print(array[r]);` in the loop somewhere

Comment: `System.out.println("Averages: " + Arrays.toString(array));`

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, you're printing the array hash code in this line

```
System.out.println("averages" + array);
```

You could use something like `Arrays.toString()`